# Use spring:message from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, call, message

I have a JQuery function who add a Table in the JSP dynamically:

```
$('#add').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

$('.tabela_procurador').before
    ('<table id="tabela_nova' + i + '" class="tabela_nova"> ' +
        '<tr> ' +
            '<td colspan="4" class="subTitulo_barra"> ' +
            '<spring:message code="representante_legal" /> '+ i +' ' +
            '</td> ' +
        '</tr> ' +
      '</table>');
     i++
   });
});
```

But when i added this table i lost the spring:message.

There is something i can do to jquery recognize this spring:message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving spring:messages in javascript for i18n internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way for jQuery to have access to a `spring` tag. `spring:message` is processed server-side before the page is sent to the client, javascript/jQuery is processed later on the client side.

Answer (score 12):

As a workaround, put the message value in a hidden input on your jsp page. Then get its value in your javascript. In your case:

```
<c:set var="val"><spring:message code="representante_legal"/></c:set>
<input id="representante_legal" type="hidden" value="${val}"/>
```

In your javascript (using jquery) you can then use it as follows:

```
$('#representante_legal').val()
```

Comment: how can i do it without the jquery tag?

Comment: @ishanbakshi `document.getElementById("representative_legal').value`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `<spring:message code="representante_legal" />` is in a JSP, if that tag is in a javascript file, it will never be translated to the localized string.

JSP files are compiled before they are sent to the requesting client, while javascript is served as static content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the spring:message is in the js file, thats why its not working.

Answer (score 2):

In your JSP, you can assign the `spring:message` to a javascript variable, making available to your other jQuery code:

```
# In .JSP
<script type="text/javascript">
  var abc="<spring:message code="representante_legal"/>";
</script>
```