# Access messages.properties value from javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a code like this on my JavaScript file `x.js`

```
alert("<spring:message code='plants.selectedPlant.name' javaScriptEscape='true' />");
```

In a file `messages.properties` I have the line:

```
plants.selectedPlant.name = Roses
```

But it just alerts the text `<spring:message code='plants.selectedPlant.name' javaScriptEscape='true' />` but not the value.

I'm not importing anything on my JS file.

Comment: JS files are not usually "rendered" as GSP files (unless you are using a plugin or wiring them manually). So the GSP syntax will not work. You can put that code inside a `<script>` tag in your calling GSP page and it should work.

Comment: The GSParse plugin might help http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving spring:messages in javascript for i18n internationalization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization)

Answer (score 2):

One useful trick is to do something like this:

HTML

```
<span id="selectedPlantName" display="none">
    <spring:message code='plants.selectedPlant.name' javaScriptEscape='true' />
</span>
```

JS (Assuming you use jQuery)

```
alert($("#selectedPlantName").text());
```

Or

take a look at the accepted answer in this question:

[Resolving spring:messages in javascript for i18n internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Pedro works fine (and I upvoted it), but in my opinion this is not the cleanest solution because you define a span with id, display etc. just to access the value later. Imagine having 20 messages - this will be a lot of unnecessary code. I would keep it simple and use plain JavaScript:

```
var myText = ""
if(locale === "de") {
  myText = "<German Text>"
} else{
  myText = "<English text>"
}
```