# Get message from spring resource bundle by js

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, internationalization

Normally I retrieve i18n messages via `<spring:message code="" />` tag in jsp. But as response of ajax query I get message code in i18n property file. How can I get message by this code via JS?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `MessageSource` to your controller and return a `String` message from that controller. Simply:

```
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@RequestMapping(value="/myajax", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getMyAjaxMessage() {
    return messageSource.getMessage(..); // use your proper arguments or extract from request parameters

}
```

javascript (assuming jquery is used):

```
$.get('/myajax', function(data){
    // do whatever you want with data (will contain your message)
});
```

Here are docs:

[MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html)

[jquery get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "normal" way to get messages from JS, but you have two solutions:

First solution: by an Ajax call.

Second solution : Send you're value at the loading of the page in hidden input html

```
<c:set var="val"><spring:message code="username"/></c:set>
<input id="username" type="hidden" value="${val}"/>
```

In your javascript (using jquery) you can then use it as follows:

```
$('#username').val()
```