# How to internationalize Javascript Content with Spring I18N?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

How Can I Internationalize Strings located in **Javascript** File while Building a **Spring MVC** WebApp ?

I'm using `<spring:message code="label1" />` to Internationalize some static Strings In the **JSP** Files, but what about error messages located in my js files for example? is there a way to resolve  internationalization without including the plain js code in the jsp file ?

I thought about creating a list of values, one for each error, and proceed with ajax calls whenever the page is refreshed, so I can get the right message according the value of the *lang* variable, but is it wise to do so ?!

Comment: working code/example posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving spring:messages in javascript for i18n internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this piece of code in some common jsp , say `header.jsp`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSystemLocale() {
    var systemLocale ='<%=RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)%>';
    return systemLocale;
}

function getResource(){
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'JS_Messages', 
        path: getContextPath()+'/resource-bundles/JS_Messages/', 
        mode:'both', 
        language:getSystemLocale(),
        callback: function() {
            jQuery.i18n.prop('error_message');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Structure will something as below. It will load all the properties files from the given path and search for the variable based on locale.

Remember the naming convention of file , ending with locale.

Need to include `jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9` for the same.

and simply in javascript you can access the `key` as `alert(error_occured);`

[image]