# Resolving spring i18n messages from extjs files

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, extjs, internationalization

Spring has its strategy to make the internationalisation in our spring project by declaring its beans.
to access the messages from jsp files we use

```
<spring:message code="messages.field">
```

Thats ok for jsp files but what about extjs(javascript) files ?

for example I have login.js must use the i18n messages:

```
items: [ {
        fieldLabel: **// here I must get the field messages.username//**,
        name: 'j_username',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e) {
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    submitForm();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Temporarily, I created my own solution without using spring i18n beans and may it will be helpfully as a solution if we don't have an approch to implement i18n with spring from extjs.however it's not to say that my solution don't present some disadvantages that I will list them at the end of this post.

first create a controller I18nController.java, this controller will be the target of the incoming requests that have the pattern /i18n.js,
its responsibility to create a javascript variable i18n and return the response as a contentType  = javascript.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/i18n.js", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void i18n(HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException,
        IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/javascript;charset=UTF-8");

    byte[] output = buildResponse(locale);
    response.setContentLength(output.length);

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(output);
    out.flush();
}
private byte[] buildResponse(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/messages", locale);

    Map<String, String> messages = Maps.newHashMap();
    Enumeration<String> e = rb.getKeys();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = e.nextElement();
        messages.put(key, rb.getString(key));
    }

    String output =  "var i18n = "+ jsonHandler.writeValueAsString(messages) + ";";
```

Second, in any jsp/html files I just use :

```
<script src ="i18n.js"></script>
```

So by that I can access to my variable from any extjs files and resolve the i18n messages:

```
items: [ {
        fieldLabel: i18n.user_username,
        name: 'j_username',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e) {
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    submitForm();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

disadvantages:

1. why using my own solution whereas spring give the classes to implements the same solution(make the project totally spring)
2. If my propoerties file messages_en.preoperties has a huge entries and lets say that the js file will use only 2 fields, here, i loaded the full entries :( ==> bad performance.

So then, how can I resolve i18n messages from extjs and using spring without using my solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218970/resolving-springmessages-in-javascript-for-i18n-internationalization#answer-6242840

Comment: Hello @ssc yes thats really help thank you :), juste I must use      `<script type="text/javascript">
    var messages = new Array();
    messages['login_title'] = "<spring:message code='login_title' javaScriptEscape='true' />";
</script>`.  <br/> thanks to javaScriptEscape too lol :)