# Multi language support using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm working on JavaScript based web app. I want JSON based multiple language integration. Which one is best library (without jQuery) to provide multi language support?

Comment: I think this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228835/best-practice-javascript-and-multilanguage

Answer (score 1):

Actually working with angularjs and angular-translate has covered all my needs on that field. You can get the translations from a js or a JSON as you please. It sometimes has problems with scopes and cached translations but everything is easily solvable. Have a look at it: 
http://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: If you know about AngularJs and love it, this library is nice to use... . I Love this.Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any library, but just using js objects:

```
var hi = {"english": "hi",
          "italian": "ciao",
          "spanish": "hola"};
var LANGUAGE = "spanish"; // choose language with your code
alert(hi[LANGUAGE]);
```

Returns

> hola

Moreover, you could use different files for each language:

```
// spanish.js
texts = {"hi": "hola",
         "howareyou": "¿Que tal?"};

// italian.js
texts = {"hi": "ciao",
         "howareyou": "Come stai?"};

// main html file (for example):
<script src="italian.js"></script> <!-- choose language file with your code -->
<script>    
     alert(texts["howareyou"]);
</script>
```

Returns

> Come stai?

However, there are many ways to do this, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228835/best-practice-javascript-and-multilanguage).

*P.S. Sorry for any language mistake :)*